# error install ros grovy in raspbian

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want install ros grovy in my raspberry, i chose ros base version but to point 5.6 when i launch the command:

> sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -yr

it returns the error:

> apt: failed to detect succesful installation of [python-rosdep]
> apt: failed to detect succesful installation of [python-rospkg]
> apt: failed to detect succesful installation of [python-catkin-pkg]

can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58293/error-install-ros-grovy-in-raspbian/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The binary UBUNTU package repository does not include **ARM** packages, only **i386** and **x86_64**.

For your platform, you will need to [install from sources](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0